# No video shown when using jwplayer to connect to RTMP stream

Tags: video, streaming, jwplayer, rtmp

I have been following [this tutorial](http://nerdlogger.com/2013/11/09/streaming-1080p-video-using-raspberry-pi-or-beaglebone-black/) to stream the video from my Logitech C920 webcam with a Raspberry Pi. Before explaining what my current issue is, I would like to note that the Webcam and the Pi are working fine, i.e. I can successfully stream the video using, for example, VLC and cvlc:

```
cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0:chroma=h264:width=1920:height=1080 --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=192.168.0.8:8080,name=stream,mime=video/ts}' -vvv
```

But I would like to watch the stream from a webpage, so I downloaded jwplayer, put it on a folder on my webserver and created this HTML page to watch it:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jwplayer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myElement-teststream">Loading the player...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement-teststream").setup({
        playlist: [{
            sources@: [{
                file: "rtmp:192.168.0.8:1935/live/teststream"
            }]
        }],
        height: 1080,
        primary: "flash",
        width: 1920
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`192.168.0.8` is the IP address of the Pi. When I go to localhost, however, no players appears, I can only see the div "Loading the player..."

I have launched the streaming server, and this is the output that shows that it is listening on port 1935:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                     Services|
+---+---------------+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| c |      ip       | port|   protocol stack name   |     application name    |
+---+---------------+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|tcp|        0.0.0.0| 1112|           inboundJsonCli|                    admin|
+---+---------------+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|tcp|        0.0.0.0| 1935|              inboundRtmp|              appselector|
+---+---------------+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|tcp|        0.0.0.0| 8081|             inboundRtmps|              appselector|
+---+---------------+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|tcp|        0.0.0.0| 8080|             inboundRtmpt|              appselector|
+---+---------------+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|tcp|        0.0.0.0| 6666|           inboundLiveFlv|              flvplayback|
+---+---------------+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|tcp|        0.0.0.0| 9999|             inboundTcpTs|              flvplayback|
+---+---------------+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|udp|        0.0.0.0|10000|             inboundUdpTs|              flvplayback|
+---+---------------+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|tcp|        0.0.0.0|  554|              inboundRtsp|              flvplayback|
+---+---------------+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|tcp|        0.0.0.0| 6665|           inboundLiveFlv|             proxypublish|
+---+---------------+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|tcp|        0.0.0.0| 8989|         httpEchoProtocol|            samplefactory|
+---+---------------+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|tcp|        0.0.0.0| 8988|             echoProtocol|            samplefactory|
+---+---------------+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|tcp|        0.0.0.0| 1111|    inboundHttpXmlVariant|                  vptests|
+---+---------------+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
/crtmpserver/src/crtmpserver.cpp:277 GO! GO! GO! (2384)
```

And then I capture with this command:

```
./capture -F -o -c0|avconv -re -i - -vcodec copy -f  rtsp -metadata title=teststream rtsp://192.168.0.8:554/live
```

Now, I can access the stream with VLC using `rtmp://192.168.0.8:1935/live/teststream`, but not from the HTML page.

Everything seems to be working fine, and the webcam lights up blue, but the player just doesn't appear. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a playlist with one item, and your RTMP URL is malformed. Also no need for the "primary" attribute, because RTMP is a Flash protocol - it can't be displayed in HTML5 mode anyway. So, try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement-teststream").setup({
        file: "rtmp://192.168.0.8:1935/live/teststream",
        height: 1080,
        width: 1920
    });
</script>
```

I'm not a "streaming guy," so I'm not sure about the format of the file. See this page about the setup: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1430358-using-rtmp-streaming

Comment: Argh dat URL! I believe that's what the problem was. This is what I get by using Notepad for simple jobs. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it was a simple problem. Those are the kind I like. ;)

Comment: Nice, glad you got it! :)